# Is it a good practice to move constants to the top of a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

In the snippet below, I set

```
privates.RADIX = 10;
```

instead of just using `10` in the succeedinf code.  Is this good practice or anal retentive?

```
function peakOut = function (elem, offset, delay, callback) {
    var privates = {};

    // constants initialization

    privates.RADIX = 10;
    privates.GRAN_TIME = 15;
    privates.GRAN_DIST = 1;
    privates.UNITS = 'px';

    // privates initialization

    privates.el = elem;
    privates.start = parseInt($P.getComputedStyle(privates.el).getPropertyValue("top"),
            privates.RADIX);

    privates.status = 'down';
    privates.end = privates.start + offset;
    privates.current = privates.start;
    privates.id = null;

    (function next() {
        if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current < privates.end)) {
            privates.current += privates.GRAN_DIST;
            privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
            if (!privates.id) {
                privates.id = $P.setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
            }
        } else if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current === privates.end)) {
            privates.status = 'up';
            $R.resetInterval(privates);
            $P.setTimeout(next, delay);
        } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current > privates.start)) {
            privates.current -= privates.GRAN_DIST;
            privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
            if (!privates.id) {
                privates.id = $P.setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
            }
        } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current === privates.start)) {
            $R.resetInterval(privates);
            callback();
        }
    }());
};
```

Comment: In general, you can never be too anal when writing code.

Comment: I agree, any other pointers for making this code stronger?

Comment: In general, you can never be too anal.

Comment: While I agree with @voithos this is good practice, I must say...this is a subjective question that teeters on the edge of being flagged.

Comment: @Sword...thanks. (insert sarcasm here).

Comment: The radix argument to `parseInt()` is usually well understood. In fact, in this case I would say it's superfluous. Otherwise, of course, constants are better than magic values.

Comment: This would be a better fit for codereview btw.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you'll get any performance enhancements in JavaScript from doing this, but it's certainly good practice for readability and maintainability's sake.

It can be good to separate out constants, since if the value is used in multiple places, you only need to change it in one place if you need to update the value.  It also serves as a signal to other coders (or yourself, in the future) what the value signifies, instead of an arbitrary number appearing in the code.

Comment: yea well, vote to re-open, smarty mcGee.